# dictionary in python tkinter not hiding button in grid even with grid_forget()

Tags: python, grid, tkinter

EDIT 2: I realized that I forgot to change a variable name at the top to the dictionary... I am very mad now.

EDIT: I changed all these exec's to a dictionary.

First of all, please don't rage at me for using exec()/eval(). It was a last resort, and I'm not taking input for this. brute force writing out variable names seems too lengthy, and I can't think of a better way to do this.

Anyways, I am writing a calendar application in python tkinter, and changing the month has become a problem for me. In a calendar, whenever someone changes a month, the days obviously begin on a different day of the week (May 2014 begins on a Thursday, and June 2014 on a Sunday).

In order to display the days of the month, though, I gave each day a button and its own special variable name using

```
exec('self.daynum'+str(7*(w-2)+d)+
     ' = Button(text=day, width=2)')
```

where w and d were variables for the week number and day number. So, when I want to hide these buttons, I believe I should use

```
exec('self.daynum'+str(day)+'.grid_forget()')
```

where day is looped over 0-35 and clears the whole grid(in theory). But, instead it raises an AttributeError, insisting that these variables do not exist.

Is there a way to fix this and hide the buttons I don't want, or suggestions on how to remodel the program to not use 
these (but still hide buttons I don't want)?

Comment: Could you keep all your `Button` instances in a dict instead of using `exec`? Then you would just do: `self.daynums[str(7*(w-2)+d)] = Button(text=day, width=2)` and `self.daynums[str(day)].grid_forget()`.

Comment: WHOOOA that actually sounds like a good idea. Let me see...

Comment: It still doesn't 'forget' all of the buttons.

Comment: I'm not familiar enough with tkinter to help you with that part. I just wanted to suggest something to help you avoid having to use `exec` all over the place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no good way to fix this fundamentally flawed approach. There is a much simpler approach, which is to use a dictionary to hold your widgets:

```
widgets = {}
for daynum in range(31):
    widgets[daynum] = Button(text=str(day), width = 2)
...
widgets[daynum].grid_forget()
```

Doing this will make your code much easier to manage.

Comment: Yeah, I changed to a dictionary. But, the grid_forget() still isn't working.

Comment: @kevin: the error should tell you exactly what's wrong. Assume it is telling you the literal truth. If it says something doesn't exist, it doesn't. Either there is a typo, you're accessing a different, local variable instead of a global or instance variable, you're trying to forget it before you create it the first time, and so on. We can't help you because you didn't give us enough information.

Comment: Sorry for being nooby, but now I'm getting a keyerror. (Before I was using try: except) How do I fix that?

Comment: Keyerror mens you are using a key (the stuff inside []) that doesn't exist. I can't tell you why it doesn't exist. Maybe you haven't created it, maybe you have a typo, maybe you created it in a different dictionary, ...

Answer (score 0):

Using lists and dicts, you really don't ever need to use eval/exec.
The following example creates a calendar of a month and keeps a list of buttons.
You can have access to these buttons later using e.g. dayButtons[0].
So to hide a button later, you can do dayButtons[day].grid_forget().

```
import Tkinter as tk
import datetime

f = tk.Frame()

dayButtons = []

for day in range(1, 32):
    date = datetime.datetime(day=day, month=5, year=2014)
    _, weeknum, weekday = date.isocalendar()

    dayButton = tk.Button(None, text=str(day), width=2)
    dayButton.grid(row=weeknum, column=weekday)
    dayButtons.append(dayButton)

tk.mainloop()
```